# Terraform: aws_s3_bucket_object "An argument named "source_hash" is not expected here."

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform documentation describes source_hash as an alternative to etag when storing aws_s3_bucket_object. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object#source_hash

The issue is etag is unreliable in a number of circumstances and using etag to prevent unnecessary updates will not work.

source_hash is the documented alternative, but I cannot get the syntax correct:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "NessusAgent_0_1_x64_manifest" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.SSMContent.id
  key    = "NessusAgent-10.0.1-x64/manifest.json"
  source = "../Infrastructure/NessusAgent-10.0.1-x64/manifest.json"
  server_side_encryption = "aws:kms"
  source_hash = filemd5("../Infrastructure/NessusAgent-10.0.1-x64/manifest.json")
}
```

Results:

```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on ..\Infrastructure\aws_s3_bucket.SSMContent.tf line 32, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "NessusAgent_0_1_x64_manifest":
│   32:   source_hash = filemd5("../Infrastructure/NessusAgent-10.0.1-x64/manifest.json")
│
│ An argument named "source_hash" is not expected here.
```

Is my syntax wrong. My configuration:

```
Terraform v1.1.4
on windows_386
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.37.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `source_hash` argument for the `aws_s3_bucket_resource_object` was implemented in version 3.50.0 of the provider: [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#3500-july-15-2021). You will need to update the provider from `3.37.0` to `~> 3.50` accordingly.